# What is this monster's AC in White Plume Mountain?

Tags: published-adventures, adnd-1e

In the original *White Plume Mountain*,

> at the end of one of the corridors (in area 27) there is an ogre mage named Qesnef, described as follows:
>
>  > AC: 1, HD: 5+2, MV: 9"/15", HP: 35, AT: 1, D: 1-12, SA: [irrelevant], SD: Regenerates 1 point per round also wears a Ring of Protection +3 on his left hand and a Ring of Mirror Images (5 charges) on his right.

How does one determine this monster's actual AC? In other words, **is the *Ring of Protection +3* already factored in to the listed AC of 1**?

This sort of monster is usually AC 4, which would seem to imply that the *Ring* is factored in, but being a unique/named monster I wasn't sure if there was some special rule that applied.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stat blocks in AD&D adventures are always the final calculated values, whether they're named creatures or stock.

> Qesnef has AC 1, as indicated.